# Team Services CI build with VS2017 hosted agent doesn't support docker project version 2.0

Tags: docker, azure-devops

ASP.NET Core 2 project with docker support added in VS 2017, runs fine locally but build fails in VSTS build with following error:

2018-06-29T16:07:50.4095117Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(151,5): Error : The project version '2.0' is not supported by the current Visual Studio Tools for Containers.

I am trying to build in Team Services and release to an App Service for Containers in Azure.

docker-compose.dcproj contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.Docker.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectVersion>2.0</ProjectVersion>
    <DockerTargetOS>Linux</DockerTargetOS>
    <ProjectGuid>cc9f4ebc-dd9f-4592-9533-b4954b467670</ProjectGuid>
    <DockerLaunchAction>LaunchBrowser</DockerLaunchAction>
    <DockerServiceUrl>http://localhost:{ServicePort}</DockerServiceUrl>
    <DockerServiceName>status</DockerServiceName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="docker-compose.override.yml">
      <DependentUpon>docker-compose.yml</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="docker-compose.yml" />
     <None Include=".dockerignore" />
   </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Can you show the whole detail build logs by setting system.debug as true? And can you also share your project (or a example project with the same build error) in one dribe?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT - [Example Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fRLu3RlPWmonRAkgMLC4iB3G96eJNzJg/view?usp=sharing) - [Logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CDXCV7RdSiAKBGzOwSgj1UzMkKAGKhNB/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are using Hosted VS2017 agent, it only has VS2017 installed and only the windows container for docker can be use. So please make below changes (as the shared example project for example):

1. Change `docker-compose.dcproj` file

   - Change ProjectVersion from `2.0` to `2.1`
   - Change DockerTargetOS from `Linux` to `Windows`
2. Change `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` file

   - Change the version from `3` to `3.4`

Then the project can build successful by Hosted VS2017 agent.
And this is the [modified project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApIKkY1MTjMRhDQf9uTACG-YgjI6) based on you shared.

BTW: you can also user [private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) to build your project. If you can build successful locally, then use the private agent can mostly build the project successfully by VSTS build.

Comment: Thanks @MarinaLiu-MSFT that worked perfectly and I was able to get the build to work with the Preview Hosted Linux Build Agent.

Comment: This actually also helped me out with a custom/private VS 2017 agent created from a definition downloaded from VSTS, I am doing a course in Pluralsight with Docker and upgrading ProjectVersion of dcproj file and the version setting in the two Yaml files helped me out.